# Java problem: src/main class not compiled in src/test

Tags: testing, mockito

I have test class(using mockito) in src/test which referring a class in src/main within same project. my reference class in testclass showing java problem with compilation error. i am using gradle build and STS ide.

any suggestion would help me lot. thank you!

Comment: are you trying test or build? can you post the error

Comment: I am not trying test or build. just imported project in eclipse and it showing compilation error in eclipse. error type: Java problem in problems tap.

Comment: Do you have a minute to imagine sitting at the A-end of Q&A? Can you imagine how hard it is to give a helpful answer supplied with just 6 sentences but no detailed error message, no code, no...whatever.